# Android: WebView simple app

Tags: android, webview

I am learning Android development and have completed the first app (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html). Now, I added a second text field and a second button. The idea is that the text that the user will enter in the text field will be used as an input in a Google Search Engine.

So I did the following:

Modified the `AndroidManifest.xml` to add the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.

Modified my `MainActivity.java` to add a call to my new activity:

```
/** Called when the user taps the Search button */
    public void searchMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplaySearchActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Then, created a new activity that has a WebView and, for now just displays the main page of `Google.com`

```
public class DisplaySearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_search);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Finally, my `activity_display_search.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.DisplaySearchActivity">

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I click the `Search` button the app takes me to the Search WebView, but nothing happens. What am I missing here?

Comment: `https` not `http`

Comment: First it seems like you're not doing anything with the `message` variable you  created and passed through the `Intent` to your display message, was that intentional?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, there's something else missing, the app page still doesn't load.

Comment: @Brian, correct. For the moment I just want to load Google.com on that activity. Then i'll pass `message` as query

Comment: You have no constraints on your ConstraintLayout

Comment: @Adhy, can you try to see if you can get `WebView` to work without transitioning to another Activity? Just try to get it to work in your main Activity. Also, just to isolate the issue further, can you try to change the `ConstraintLayout` to a simple `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Hi @Brian! I create a new project with the WebView as main activity to load Google.com. It does not load :( I tried to open a web page on Chrome and it crashes. The Google bar on the phone does not load anything either, so I guess the problem is with the emulator

Comment: That is quite strange, maybe you should see if you can load it on a phone or if you want to try another emulator, my favorite that I use is Genymotion (best Android emulation in my opinion).

Comment: So I logged into the physical machine and started the emulator. The Button does take me to Google, which is sufficient for now. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to provide a WebViewClient for your WebView.

```
public class DisplaySearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_search);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Niels. I still get a blank screen. Is there anything else I should do besides what you mention?

Comment: In fact, the WebView reference does not require the JS part - https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: @AdhySatya removed enableJavascript to keep answer more concise.